# How to transform a dataframe with boolean values to a set of sequences?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have a dataframe with boolean values:

[image]

And I want to transform it into another dataframe:

[image]

a, b and c are the columns of the first dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), reshape by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), filter only `True`s and pivot in [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df['g'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
df = df.melt('g', ignore_index=False)
df = (df[df['value']]
          .reset_index()
          .pivot_table(index='index', columns='g', values='variable', aggfunc=' '.join)
          .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))

print (df)
       0    1    2
1    b c  b c  NaN
2      b  NaN  NaN
3  a b c  a c    a
```